# Databricks-spark-xml unable to filter bad record into bad-record column when xml tag missing and schema provided

Tags: xml, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I'm reading an xml file using databricks-spark-xml dependency in scala-spark(intellij). I provide a schema and option("mode", "PERMISSIVE")
.option("columnNameOfCorruptRecord", "_BAD_record") the same name is also present in schema. When spark reads the xml file it makes the malformed record as null and doesn't put it into _BAD_record column,this results in data loss which my software can't afford to have. Help! Also thanks in advance...

can't use inferschema because it will make all the datatype mismatch as string and all records will be rejected in detailed validation further in the pipeline.

Also tried to generate schema from SchemaConverter from org.zalando.spark.jsonSchema, no success, client prefers this method

```
    object SecondXmlScalaObject {
        val schema = new StructType().add("AccountOwner", new   StructType().add("Primary", new StructType().add("CISInfo", new StructType().add("CustomerNumber", LongType))
        .add("FirstName", StringType)
        .add("LastName", StringType)
        .add("CurrentAddress", new StructType().add("City", StringType)
        .add("State", StringType)
        .add("Street2", StringType)
        .add("Zip", LongType))))
        .add("BankNumber", StringType)
        .add("DepositAccountNumber", StringType)
        .add("ProductMarketingName", StringType)
        .add("_BAD_RECORDS",StringType)

        def main(args: Array[String]) = {
            val conf = new SparkConf()
                .setAppName("xmlSparkEval")
                .setMaster("local")

            val sc = new SparkContext(conf);

            val spark = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate()

            val fileContents = Source.fromFile("/resources/jsonschema.json").getLines.mkString

            val schema1 = SchemaConverter.convertContent(fileContents)

            val df = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
                .option("rowTag", "PrintApplication")
                .option("ignoreSurroundingSpaces", true)
                .option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls", true)
                .option("mode", "PERMISSIVE")
                .option("columnNameOfCorruptRecord", "_BAD_record")
                .schema(schema)
                //.schema(schema1)
                .load("abc.xml")

            df.printSchema()
            df.show(false)
        }
    }
```

actual(unacceptable) results: for malformed xml record all the columns become null in dataframe

acceptable: malformed(tag missing) records should be put in _BAD_RECORDS